# How can make one table column other table column names alias?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, olap-cube

I have 2 tables. I need select from 1st table columns which are in 2nd table 1st columns.

Definition: The 2nd table has 2 columns which are 1st column show which columns(number) we must select from the 1st table, the 2nd column shows that what must be this column heading result screen.

For creating virtual tables I add SQL this tables.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqdQb.png)
1st Table

```
select '1' as joinable_column_id ,'First_column_name' from dual
union all
select '2' as joinable_column_id,'Second_column_name' from dual
union all 
select '3' as joinable_column_id,'Third_column_name' from dual
union all
select '4' as joinable_column_id,'Fourth_column_name' from dual;
```

2nd table

```
select 'id', 'column_1','column_2','column_3','column_4','column_5','column_6','column_7','column_8','column_9' from dual
union all
select 'id', 'column_row_1','column_row_2','column_row_3','column_row_4','column_row_5','column_row_6','column_row_7','column_row_8','column_row_9' from dual;
```

[Result screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kgOZ.jpg)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text instead of images (or links to images.)

Comment: @jarlh I use Oracle database.Stack recommended mysql that's why I used my-sql as tag.

Comment: I can split question into 2 question.
  1) How can use table rows as other table heading?
  2) How can select one table columns by its sequence number ?

Comment: I have no idea what this question is about.It might help if you could add an example of what you are trying to achieve including sample data and expected result as text to the quesion.

Comment: In definition I have explain as much as possible.And added excel picture for clarification.
I cann't add text formatted clarification for result screen.

Comment: @P.Salmon How can I show one table rows other table column header as alias ?

Comment: @Bahruz Aghalarov - Your questions are not understandable.. We need to understand the question before we can answer.. Do you want the data from table1 column1 to be column name in table2? Do you want to use pivot to convert the column data into column names?

Comment: You can’t, via normal sql, parameterize column aliases.  You could do this with some dynamic SQL, but it won’t be pretty, it’ll be hard to maintain, and may suffer performance issues.   Reconsider what you are trying to do and why you are doing it.

Comment: I have used listagg function.It is convenient for make rows as columns for select.

select listagg(t2.name,',') within group (order by t1.id ) from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id(this 1st column);